# imageview.hidden = false // for selected ^ true for not selected in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

given below is my code to make image visible or not on multiple selection in uitableview but there is only 1 problem it doesnot work in realtime it works after scrolling.

i think i have mistake in picking cell of myTableView

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.selected)
    {
        cell.imageView.hidden = false;
    }
    else{
        cell.imageView.hidden = true;
    }
```

writing this code in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

,

Comment: What method have you included this code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the exect solution of your problem

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

        [TbView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        if (!([selectedIndexPath containsObject:indexPath]))
        {
            [selectedIndexPath addObject:indexPath];
            [[TbView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        }
        else
        {
            [selectedIndexPath removeObject:indexPath];
            [[TbView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.hidden=!cell.imageView.hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a subclass of UITableViewCell and overriding the `setSelected` method:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    if (self.selected == selected)
        return;

    [super setSelected:selected];

    if (selected)
    {
        self.imageView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.imageView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

P.S. don't forget to call `setSelected` on `super` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use following two delegate method of `UITableView`.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // this method use for previous selected row/cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.hidden = false;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // this method use for selcted row/cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.hidden = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier, simpler action than all this. Refresh table after selection has been made.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
...


//then reload table
[tableView reloadData];

}
```